# Full speed on ITG3200 with Arduino

Tags: arduino, accelerometer, sensors, arduino-uno, gyroscope

I am using a ITG3200(Sparkfun breakout board) for my project. I was trying to boost the sample rate of ITG3200 to over 2K HZ. I have already soldered two 2.2K pull-up resistors on the sensor and close the clockin pads. I encountered a few problems here.   It was connected to a Arduino Uno.

1. The highest sample rate I can achieve was around 500 Hz. I have changed the clock to 400K. However, without doing that, I should still get something over 1000 Hz, right? I attached my code below.

Any comments or suggestions would be greatly appriecated!

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include <Wire.h>

// Pin definitions - Shift registers:
int enPin = 13;  // Shift registers' Output Enable pin
int latchPin = 12;  // Shift registers' rclk pin
int clkPin = 11;  // Shift registers' srclk pin
int clrPin = 10;  // shift registers' srclr pin
int datPin = 8;  // shift registers' SER pin

int show = 0;
int lastMax = 0;


//This is a list of registers in the ITG-3200. Registers are parameters that determine how the sensor will behave, or they can hold data that represent the
//sensors current status.
//To learn more about the registers on the ITG-3200, download and read the datasheet.
char WHO_AM_I = 0x00;
char SMPLRT_DIV= 0x15;//0x15
char DLPF_FS = 0x16;
char GYRO_XOUT_H = 0x1D;
char GYRO_XOUT_L = 0x1E;
char GYRO_YOUT_H = 0x1F;
char GYRO_YOUT_L = 0x20;
char GYRO_ZOUT_H = 0x21;
char GYRO_ZOUT_L = 0x22;

//This is a list of settings that can be loaded into the registers.
//DLPF, Full Scale Register Bits
//FS_SEL must be set to 3 for proper operation
//Set DLPF_CFG to 3 for 1kHz Fint and 42 Hz Low Pass Filter
char DLPF_CFG_0 = 0;//1
char DLPF_CFG_1 = 0;//2
char DLPF_CFG_2 = 0;//4
char DLPF_FS_SEL_0 = 8;
char DLPF_FS_SEL_1 = 16;

char itgAddress = 0x69;

// Some of the math we're doing in this example requires the number of bargraph boards
// you have connected together (normally this is one, but you can have a maximum of 8).

void setup()
// Runs once upon reboot
{
  // Setup shift register pins
  pinMode(enPin, OUTPUT);  // Enable, active low, this'll always be LOW
  digitalWrite(enPin, LOW);  // Turn all outputs on
  pinMode(latchPin, OUTPUT);  // this must be set before calling shiftOut16()
  digitalWrite(latchPin, LOW);  // start latch low
  pinMode(clkPin, OUTPUT);  // we'll control this in shiftOut16()
  digitalWrite(clkPin, LOW);  // start sck low
  pinMode(clrPin, OUTPUT);  // master clear, this'll always be HIGH
  digitalWrite(clrPin, HIGH);  // disable master clear
  pinMode(datPin, OUTPUT);  // we'll control this in shiftOut16()
  digitalWrite(datPin, LOW);  // start ser low

  // To begin, we'll turn all LEDs on the circular bar-graph OFF
  digitalWrite(latchPin, LOW);  // first send latch low
  shiftOut16(0x0000);
  digitalWrite(latchPin, HIGH);  // send latch high to indicate data is done sending

  Serial.begin(230400);

  //Initialize the I2C communication. This will set the Arduino up as the 'Master' device.
  Wire.begin();

  //Read the WHO_AM_I register and print the result
  char id=0; 
  id = itgRead(itgAddress, 0x00);  
  Serial.print("ID: ");
  Serial.println(id, HEX);

  //Configure the gyroscope
  //Set the gyroscope scale for the outputs to +/-2000 degrees per second
  itgWrite(itgAddress, DLPF_FS, (DLPF_FS_SEL_0|DLPF_FS_SEL_1|DLPF_CFG_0));
  //Set the sample rate to 100 hz
  itgWrite(itgAddress, SMPLRT_DIV, 0);
}

void loop()
// Runs continuously after setup() ends
{
  static int zero = 0;

  // Create variables to hold the output rates.
  int xRate, yRate, zRate;
  float range = 3000.0;
  int divisor;

  divisor = range / 8;

  //Read the x,y and z output rates from the gyroscope.
  xRate = int(float(readX()) / divisor - 0.5) * -1;
  yRate = int(float(readY()) / divisor - 0.5) * -1;
  zRate = int(float(readZ()) / divisor - 0.5);

  //Print the output rates to the terminal, seperated by a TAB character.

  Serial.print(xRate);
  Serial.print('\t');
  Serial.print(yRate);
  Serial.print('\t');
  Serial.println(zRate);  
  Serial.print('\t');
//  Serial.println(zero);


//  fillTo(zRate);

  //Wait 10ms before reading the values again. (Remember, the output rate was set to 100hz and 1reading per 10ms = 100hz.)
//  delay(10);
}


// This function will write a value to a register on the itg-3200.
// Parameters:
//   char address: The I2C address of the sensor. For the ITG-3200 breakout the address is 0x69.
//   char registerAddress: The address of the register on the sensor that should be written to.
//   char data: The value to be written to the specified register.
void itgWrite(char address, char registerAddress, char data)
{
  //Initiate a communication sequence with the desired i2c device
  Wire.beginTransmission(address);
  //Tell the I2C address which register we are writing to
  Wire.write(registerAddress);
  //Send the value to write to the specified register
  Wire.write(data);
  //End the communication sequence
  Wire.endTransmission();
}

//This function will read the data from a specified register on the ITG-3200 and return the value.
//Parameters:
//  char address: The I2C address of the sensor. For the ITG-3200 breakout the address is 0x69.
//  char registerAddress: The address of the register on the sensor that should be read
//Return:
//  unsigned char: The value currently residing in the specified register
unsigned char itgRead(char address, char registerAddress)
{
  //This variable will hold the contents read from the i2c device.
  unsigned char data=0;

  //Send the register address to be read.
  Wire.beginTransmission(address);
  //Send the Register Address
  Wire.write(registerAddress);
  //End the communication sequence.
  Wire.endTransmission();

  //Ask the I2C device for data
  Wire.beginTransmission(address);
  Wire.requestFrom(address, 1);

  //Wait for a response from the I2C device
  if(Wire.available()){
    //Save the data sent from the I2C device
    data = Wire.read();
  }

  //End the communication sequence.
  Wire.endTransmission();

  //Return the data read during the operation
  return data;
}

//This function is used to read the X-Axis rate of the gyroscope. The function returns the ADC value from the Gyroscope
//NOTE: This value is NOT in degrees per second. 
//Usage: int xRate = readX();
int readX(void)
{
  int data=0;
  data = itgRead(itgAddress, GYRO_XOUT_H)<<8;
  data |= itgRead(itgAddress, GYRO_XOUT_L);  

  return data;
}

//This function is used to read the Y-Axis rate of the gyroscope. The function returns the ADC value from the Gyroscope
//NOTE: This value is NOT in degrees per second. 
//Usage: int yRate = readY();
int readY(void)
{
  int data=0;
  data = itgRead(itgAddress, GYRO_YOUT_H)<<8;
  data |= itgRead(itgAddress, GYRO_YOUT_L);  

  return data;
}

//This function is used to read the Z-Axis rate of the gyroscope. The function returns the ADC value from the Gyroscope
//NOTE: This value is NOT in degrees per second. 
//Usage: int zRate = readZ();
int readZ(void)
{
  int data=0;
  data = itgRead(itgAddress, GYRO_ZOUT_H)<<8;
  data |= itgRead(itgAddress, GYRO_ZOUT_L);  

  return data;
}

void fillTo(int place) {
  int ledOutput = 0;

  if(place > 8)
    place = 8;
  if(place < -8)
    place = -8;

  if(place >= 0) {
    for (int i = place; i >= 0; i--)
      ledOutput |= 1 << i;
  } else {
    ledOutput = 32768;
    for (int i = place; i <= 0; i++)
      ledOutput |= (ledOutput >> 1);
  }

//  Serial.println(ledOutput);

  digitalWrite(latchPin, LOW);  // first send latch low
  shiftOut16(ledOutput);  // send the ledOutput value to shiftOut16
  digitalWrite(latchPin, HIGH);  // send latch high to indicate data is done sending 
}

void shiftOut16(uint16_t data)
{
  byte datamsb;
  byte datalsb;

  // Isolate the MSB and LSB
  datamsb = (data & 0xFF00) >> 8;  // mask out the MSB and shift it right 8 bits
  datalsb = data & 0xFF;  // Mask out the LSB

  // First shift out the MSB, MSB first.
  shiftOut(datPin, clkPin, MSBFIRST, datamsb);
  // Then shift out the LSB
  shiftOut(datPin, clkPin, MSBFIRST, datalsb);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested the serial writes, the I2C port and the clock speed. Found the major issues were the redundant communication to i2c. For instance, the 6 bits data can be read in one round of i2c communication. I refered the code below: 
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ControlEverythingCommunity/ITG3200/master/Arduino/ITG-3200.ino

In addition, using Teensy is also helpful.

The speed of the output was checked by using the oscilloscope with the I2C debug function.

Answer (score 1):

500Hz means 2ms for each iteration of your loop() function. Your loop function is reading from Wire and writing to the Serial port, which may take more time than 2ms, depending on what you're sending and what your baud rate is.

Judging from your baud rate (230400), it may take roughly 0.5ms to send each measurement (estimated at 12 characters each) if there is no flow control from the other side. Try writing to serial less frequently to see if your performance goes up.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I actually found the issues before seeing your response. But yours is pointing to the right direction. The Serial port is actually not taking too much time here, since I am using Teensy, which is actually like a USB com. The biggest problem here is actually the redundant communication inside the loop. I posted my solution below.